One-tailed Bayesian correlation hypothesis with BFcorrelation, interpretation output?
For the following command:
correlationBF(df$var1, df$var2, nullInterval = c(-1, 0))

I get the resulting output
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Alt., r=0.333 -1<rho<0    : 96.40458   ±NA%
[2] Alt., r=0.333 !(-1<rho<0) : 0.06047267 ±NA%

Against denominator:
  Null, rho = 0 
---
Bayes factor type: BFcorrelation, Jeffreys-beta*

I would now like to get the BF for the hypothesis that the correlation is < 0. At first I thought it was 96.4 but I am confused because shouldn´t the BF for the alternative hypothesis be 1/96.4 instead of 0.06 then?
Or do I need to divide the two results, but why?
Any help is much appreciated!

What's the alternative hypothesis that you want to compare "correlation < 0" against?

That it´s not true, so correlation >= 0 or !(correlation < 0).

Having thought more about it, I don't think you can "mix" a point and an interval hypothesis. It's easy to check that !(correlation < 0) gives the same Bayes factor as correlation > 0 (against the point null correlation = 0). Otherwise you are correct that dividing the two rows should give you an estimate for BF for (correlation < 0) vs (correlation > 0).

The documentation is helpful. > If nullInterval is defined, then two Bayes factors will be computed: The Bayes factor for the interval against the null hypothesis that the probability is 0, and the corresponding Bayes factor for the complement of the interval. (PS. I think they mean "the correlation is 0", not the "the probability is 0".) So the first row gives BF for -1<rho<0 against rho = 0 and the second row gives BF for !(-1<rho<0) against rho = 0.

Thank you so much for your help! So just to clarify, I should NOT divide the two Bayes Factors but I should only report the first Bayes Factor to report the extent of evidence for the hypothesis that the correlation is negative, right?

I seem to be answering in comments, which is muddling things up. Sorry about that; I've written a proper answer now. The gist is that I would divide the first row by the second row to compute the Bayes factor for "correlation < 0" vs "correlation > 0". (A BF compares two hypotheses, so need to be clear what those hypotheses are.)

A Bayes factor compares two hypotheses:
$$
\begin{aligned}
BF_{12} = \frac{p(D | H_1)}{p(D | H_2)}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $D$ is the data and $H_1,H_2$ are the two competing hypotheses. Oftentimes we call $H_1$ the null hypothesis and $H_2$ the alternative hypothesis; it may be a bit clear to call them the numerator and the denominator hypothesis instead. The Bayes factor is a relative measure of support that the data $D$ provide in favor of $H_1$ against $H_2$.
In this case, $D$ is a set of paired observations $\{(x_i, y_i)\}$ drawn from a data generating process with correlation $\rho$. The question makes it clear the hypothesis of interest is $H_1: \rho < 0$ (the correlation is negative). But what's $H_2$? What do we want to compare $H_1$ against?
If we assume the correlation coefficient $\rho$ is not exactly 0, the "natural" competing hypothesis is $H_2: \rho > 0$ (the correlation is positive).
However, {BayesFactor:: correlationBF} sets up a different comparison. As the documentation explains:

If nullInterval is defined, then two Bayes factors will be computed: The Bayes factor for the interval against the null hypothesis that the probability is 0, and the corresponding Bayes factor for the complement of the interval.

Note: I think there is a typo and they mean "the correlation is 0", not the "the probability is 0".
Let's use a small dataset for illustration:
x <- c(-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1)

{BayesFactor} reports the following the interval hypothesis -1<rho<0.
bf <- correlationBF(y, x, nullInterval = c(-1, 0))
bf
#> Bayes factor analysis
#> --------------
#> [1] Alt., r=0.333 -1<rho<0    : 6.370792  ±NA%
#> [2] Alt., r=0.333 !(-1<rho<0) : 0.2441607 ±NA%
#> 
#> Against denominator:
#>   Null, rho = 0 
#> ---
#> Bayes factor type: BFcorrelation, Jeffreys-beta*

The complement of -1<rho<0 is indicated by !(-1<rho<0); perhaps we should read this as "the correlation is non-negative". But if we specify the null interval as 0<rho<1, {BayesFactor} simply flips the rows.
bf <- correlationBF(y, x, nullInterval = c(0, 1))
bf
#> Bayes factor analysis
#> --------------
#> [1] Alt., r=0.333 0<rho<1    : 0.2441607 ±NA%
#> [2] Alt., r=0.333 !(0<rho<1) : 6.370792  ±NA%
#> 
#> Against denominator:
#>   Null, rho = 0 
#> ---
#> Bayes factor type: BFcorrelation, Jeffreys-beta*

That is, even though the denominator hypothesis is "sharp": rho = 0, the interval hypothesis in the numerator of the Bayes factor doesn't include the boundary values.
So we have the Bayes factor $BF_{N,0}$ for (correlation is negative) vs (correlation is exactly 0) and the Bayes factor $BF_{P,0}$ for (correlation is positive) vs (correlation is exactly 0). Note: For clarity, I switch from indexing hypotheses with 1, 2,  ... to labeling them with "N", "P" and "0" for negative, positive and zero.
I think that $BF_{N,0}$ on its own is not a particularly meaningful measure to report as it implicitly assumes the correlation cannot be any positive number no matter how tiny.
We can however compute two alternative Bayes factors:

$BF_{N,0} / BF_{P,0}$: the Bayes factor for rho < 0 against rho > 0.
$BF_{N,0} / (BF_{P,0} + 1)$: the Bayes factor for rho < 0 against rho = 0 or rho > 0. This can be derived from the equality (a/b) / (c/b + 1) = a/(c + b) where a, b and c are the marginal probabilities $p(D | H_i)$ under the three hypotheses.

To be honest, I'm not convinced of the soundness of the second alternative. Logically, it makes sense if the prior puts a "lump" of probability on the point hypothesis $H_0: \rho = 0$. On the other hand, it may be more reasonable to argue that the true correlation is not exactly 0 (though it can be infinitesimally close to 0) and use the first alternative.

PS: I've been on something of a deep dive into Bayes factors recently, not sure why. See also these threads Hypothesis testing: Should it be done on the transformed parameter or the non-transformed? and Difficulty Obtaining Bayesfactor in Baysian Correlation in R (correlationBF from BayesFactor).
